# Internal Storage - Negative Value

Tags: internal-storage, internal-sd

I recently installed a new Custom Rom (Resurrection Remix) on my phone.

Since then, my Internal Storage has been acting weird. It's size and usage are shown as negative values as observed in the attached pictures.

[image: Settings -> Storage]
[image: Internal Shared Storage]

Apps are installed in Internal and working fine, no problem there. But I'm not able to access the files or Download other stuff like pictures and music into my internal. I have to resort to external SD card for that.

Comment: Probably want to message your ROM maintainer... That is something wrong in the code, not really much you can do.

Comment: ROM bug, contact the developer

Comment: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have MMC inserted while booting. This issue is commonly seen on Android devices running Android 7 nogaut.
If you have AOSP for Android 7 then modify the below file: 
/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/storage/StorageManager.java

Interchange the position of **mmc** and **sda** storage path

**Before**

```
private static final String[] INTERNAL_STORAGE_SIZE_PATHS = {
"/sys/block/mmcblk0/size",
"/sys/block/sda/size"
};
```

**After**

```
private static final String[] INTERNAL_STORAGE_SIZE_PATHS = {
"/sys/block/sda/size",
"/sys/block/mmcblk0/size" 
};
```